# How to Pause and Resume a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to suspend and resume a thread in Java from another class. The java code I wrote for it doesn't seem to work.
The program is written inside raspberry pi. It monitors the state of a pin in the pi. What I basically want to do is to suspend and resume the monitoring of the pin state at any point in time by the click of a button.
I am not a professional Java programmer, so I might have done something wrong.
Please can anyone look at the attached code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

//THIS IS THE CLASS THAT I WANT TO CONTROL FROM ANOTHER CLASS

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Sensor {
    static boolean threadSuspended; /////
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int PortNumber = 400;

        // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        // provision gpio pin #07 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
        final GpioPinDigitalInput myDoor = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_07, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

      while(true){
           boolean MySensor1 = myDoor.isHigh();
       Thread.sleep(20000);
           if (MySensor1 == true) {
           System.out.println("The Door is Closed");
           }
           else {
           System.out.println("The Door is Open");
           String[] arg = {};
           DoorOpen.main(arg);
            }

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                System.out.println("Server is running and listening");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    synchronized(this) {
                    while(threadSuspended) 
                       wait();

                  }
            ServerSocket SensorSock = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
            while(true){
            Socket clientSock = SensorSock.accept();
            InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
            String Message = BR.readLine();
            System.out.println(Message);
            if(Message != null){
                boolean MySensor = myDoor.isHigh();
                 if (MySensor == true) {
                    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                    PS.println("The Door is Closed");
                     }
                 else {
                    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                    PS.println("The Door is Open");
                 }
                }
            clientSock.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + PortNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    };
    t.start();
    }     
}
```

//HERE IS THE METHOD THAT IS SUPPOSED TO PAUSE AND RESUME THE THREAD

```
    public synchronized void ButtonPressed() {

        threadSuspended = !threadSuspended;

        if (!threadSuspended)
            notify();
    }
}
```

//THIS CLASS CONTROLS THE OTHER CLASS BY CALLING THE METHOD ButtonPressed()

```
public class ActSensor {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Sensor s = new Sensor();

         try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             s.ButtonPressed();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
          }
     }

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Android? Isn't Pi4J for the RasPi?

Comment: you never leave the first while loop

Comment: Use a CountDownLatch http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: @DeadChex Yes The program is written inside raspberry pi. It monitors the state of a pin in the pi. What I basically want to do is to suspend and resume the monitoring of the pin state at any point in time by the click of a button.

Comment: You have two `main` methods.  That means you're running in two processes, which means two JVMs.  You don (just) have two threads.  Simply using the same class in both programs won't allow them to talk to each other.  You need to set up some kind of inter-process communication.

Comment: @IanMcLaird "Simply using the same class in both programs won't allow them to talk to each other." Please can you elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

Both your `ActSensor` and `Sensor` classes have `public static void main(...)` methods.  So what I think you're probably doing is:

1. Starting `Sensor` to watch the pin
2. Running `ActSensor` to try to change the state of `Sensor`

That means what you have here *isn't* (just) two threads.  It's two *whole programs*.

That's not going to work the way you're hoping it will.  Java objects can easily call (public) methods from each other to communicate, but that only works when one of the objects has a reference to the other.  In order to create a reference like this, you need both of them to be loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.  Over-simplifying a little, that means they have to be in the same program.

When you start the second process with `ActSensor`, you're in a different process, so the object you get when you call `new Sensor()` is a *different object* from the one in the other running program.  In fact, there's *no way* to get a reference to the object in the other program at all.

You need to set up inter-process communication to make this work, and it's going to be more work than just calling a method.  There are lots of different approaches you can take using `Sockets` or a file they both interact with, a message queue, or something.

Alternatively, you need to make this just one program, but that will change your use case.  You'd need the `Sensor` class to start up another thread that listens for input, and takes the appropriate action.  (Note:  This will actually be required for the inter-process communication above, too)

So long story short, you have some work to do.